# Mobile Web Service Authentication

Tags: php, service, authentication, web

I am building a REST web service in PHP designed to be used with mobile devices like iOS and android. Basically, GET requests are used to return JSON data with the results for a request, and POST and DELETE requests are used to add data to the service.

Basically, I need to implement a user login / authentication system so that when a user requests data specific to them, like their own list of something, or they try and add data, they need to log in.

I know that I will need to secure the signup and authentication using SSL, but I would like to avoid re-inventing things.  I am looking for a solution for doing this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are a building a genuine REST web service, then you can't have sessions - i.e. have the user logging in once, the server then remembering the session and the user using that session for each subsequent call. For a REST service, the server will not remember "state".

> Each state can be completely understood by the representation(s) it
>   contains and the set of transitions that it provides, with the
>   transitions limited to a uniform set of actions to be understandable.

(Source: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/5841)

This actually makes your job easier, as each call to the server must come with a unique identifier to authenticate the user. Your options include sending a username/password combination, a secret key and other reference to identify the user, or possibly both. So when the user "logs in", you rememeber their details client side (i.e. in javascript in a webform, or by your application and remembered in local storage for the iPhone / Android) and then send those details with each and every call. You can use a rest call to validate the login details, but it won;t return a session.

So to answer with pseduo code:

1. HTML: User Logs In. Form is trapped by Javascript and the username/password (or other secret key) is remembered by javascript, OR
2. iOS / Android: user logs in. Form is trapped by code and remembered in local storage
3. [optional] Send username/pass/secret key to your "WhoAmI" webservice: if valid, you get a response. If not valid, you send an error. This can give immediate feedback
4. With every other call, you also send username/pass/secret key to your webservice: if valid you process the call, if not valid, you throw an error.
5. (On getting error, you ask user for new credentials).

The PHP side is simple: each and every call will read:

1. If no username/password/secret key : reject call
2. Look up username/password/secret key in database. If not valid: reject call
3. If valid: process rest of call - you have the user's details.

Obviously, you can also bolt on services that don't need authentication; this could include registration.

Comment: Thanks so much. Got most of this working :)

Right now, for testing and dev I am using it over straight HTTP and will migrate to HTTPS (SSL) when we deploy.

One of the concerns I have is since I will be sending credentials with POST messages to validate if a user can add content, those messages will have to be secured with SSL. Some of these POST forms have images and files in them.  I am not to familiar with doing this, I understand encoding text / data over SSL, since it is not a lot of actual data.  But is encoding a whole image or file over SSL a normal practice?

Comment: If you have the HTML delivered under ssl, then you also need the images delivered by ssl. It's getting more and more common for pages to be ssl'd to prevent eves dropping with wireless networks, so now nothing I'd worry about unless you are seriously worried about bandwidth/server CPU.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems that I should not have to worry about it then. - Just to be clear tho, it's not a web page I am delivering, it is form data with am image upload, from a mobile device like an iPhone.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Bundle Oauth consumer key and secret to the client app. Sign with Oauth 1 authorization header for HTTPS request. Nowaday signing is easy with oauth libraries.

For web app, no way.